# PHP ImageMagick modulateImage equivalence for CSS Saturate

Tags: css, imagick

When modifying the saturation of an image, we are doing it with CSS (saturate) with a value between 0 and 1. However, when passing it to Imagick with the command

```
$img->modulateImage(100,$saturation,100);
```

the results are not the same. We have multiplied the saturation value by 100, but the results are still not the same as what was applied in CSS.

Does anyone know the equivalence of saturation in CSS to that used by Imagick?

We need to clone the effect of css saturate() to PHP Imagick modulateImage(100,XX,100)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you provide an example input image and the output from CSS and from Imagemagick modulateImage.  Another way to do desaturation is to convert to HSV colorspace, separate out the S channel. Then do an evaluate multiply, then recombine the H, new S, V. Then convert back to sRGB.  That should be the same as doing modulate image with -define modulate:colorspace=HSV or HSB.  The default colorspace for modulateImage is HSL.  That is likely your issue.  See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/#modulate_colorspace

Comment: Sure, we have edited the question with two images. What we do is to multiply by 130 the CSS saturation, because with a *100 factor results were not good. Aproximating to 130, results are good, but not the same.

$saturacion=($saturacion*(130));

Comment: What are the images you provided?  You only have two.  I asked that you provide the input and both the CSS and Imagick output results. Also the saturation value you used in CSS and Imagemagick.